# Can't find packages, Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, gnome, wine

I'm trying to install wine 1.6 but the Terminal keeps saying it can't find the packages. And when I tried to add it to the repository it says i'm not using the correct PPA name.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine1.6/stable
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:wine1.6/stable'.
Please check that PPA name or format is correct.
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly entered the ppa name. The correct one is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```